# Enable Biztalk Failed Message Routing in Orchestration

Tags: biztalk

In Biztalk ReceivePort, we can enable failed message routing such that error message will be routed to the message box for further processing.

But for orchestration, how to enable failed message routing, same as ReceivePort?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to create your own ErrorReport message. Do this by publishing a message with ErrorReport.Type = "FailedMessage" and set the ErrorReport.Description to your exception message for example. ErrorReport.MessageType is also handy sometimes.

Be aware for the ErrorReport.Description, that you will only be able to put 255 characters in the context.

To promote something in your orchestration, do it like this:

YourMessageName(FILE.ReceivedFileName) = 'whatever.txt';

Be aware, to promote it, you would need put it in a correlation set, which would need to be used on your send shape

Comment: Where I can find the ErrorReport message schema such that I can create the ErrorReport message in the orchestration? Thanks.

Comment: @hosir There is no such schema. It is just a bunch of context properties (see the property schema in the BizTalk.System application).

Comment: Hi Pieter, how to set the context properties of a message created in Orchestration? thx

Comment: Do it like this: 

YourMessageName(FILE.ReceivedFileName) = 'whatever.txt';

Be aware, to promote it, you would need put it in a correlation set, which would need to be used on your send shape.

Answer (score 0):

The Failed Message Routing feature is not available when publishing messages from an Orchestration.

Since you have complete control over the messages published from an Orchestration, any routing error would really be an application error and represent a case the Orchestration must handle.